# How to use make use of BokehJS in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, bokehjs

I am unable to use the BokehJS library in my Angular app (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide/bokehjs.html).
I get the following error as soon as I try to call the library from my app :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/lib/index.js 3:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export { version } from "./version";
| export { index } from "./embed";
> export * as embed from "./embed";
| export * as protocol from "./protocol";
| export * as _testing from "./testing";
```

Here is a detailed step-by-step method to reproduce the issue on a "fresh" computer (I tried it on two different machines, they both get the exact same error at the end):

- install nodejs : https://nodejs.org/en/
- install angular-cli : `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- initialize a new angular project in the current directory : `ng new angular10BokehJSexample`
- enter the new project directory : `cd angular10BokehJSexample`
- *(optional)* check that the example angular app works : `npm start` and open your browser on URL http://localhost:4200
- install BokehJS : `npm install @bokeh/bokehjs`
- open your favorite text editor and change the file `src/app/app.module.ts`. Add the following line with the other imports at the top : `import * as Bokeh from '@bokeh/bokehjs'`
- *(optional)* if you start the server at this stage, it should still work fine, meaning that BokehJS can be imported successfully (that was not the case with an old version of Angular)
- still in the file `src/app/app.module.ts`, change the class decalaration at the end of the file to make it look like this :

```js
export class AppModule {

  private testBokeh(){
    var item = JSON.parse("just a test");
    Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item);
  }

}
```

*(note: this is just a stub, the code does not work. I’ve put together a more complex code that is supposed to work, but this is sufficient to reproduce my issue)*

- run `npm start` again, it cannot compile due to the error mentionned at the beginning of this question.

Any idea regarding what I am doing wrong ? I am not a frontend developer, so I am definitely out of my comfort zone here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.